# Using JSON Response from Google Places API in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I want to do some application to learn how to work with android and maps. So I want to make something simple, like showing on the map the schools or museums from a given city.

I think I have to use the Google Places API, so I read some things about it. I saw that I have to make some request to a rest server, and they will return me a json response. I understand that. But, what I don't understand is how can I "translate" those json responses into pinpoints on the map.

If you can guide me to some tutorials or some examples with this, I would appreciate that. I saw some links right here, on SO, but they were incomplete or not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use the json data as follows:
var a=new JSONObject(jsonData);

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Use the data from a to constuct the necessary objects and add it to the map.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-google-maps-places.html